# Using Match in Nested If Statement - only works on first IF Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, match

Using Excel 2007

I have data like this:

```
column 1     column 2     column 3
========     ========     ========
type 10      Type 3       Type 5
Type 2       Type 12      Type 8
Type 4       Type 3       Type 6
Type 1       Type 5       Type 11
```

And I want to put one column at the end that decodes the 3 columns and displays the column position of any of the types from 1-3. Using a column with MATCH and nested IF statement. So the decode column would look like this:

```
column 1     column 2     column 3    Type Position
========     ========     ========    ==============
type 10      Type 3       Type 5      Pos 2
Type 2       Type 12      Type 8      Pos 1
Type 4       Type 3       Type 6      Pos 2
Type 1       Type 5       Type 11     Pos 1
```

I tried using something like below but it only works on the first IF statement - this is only for the first two columns as I build the statement up and make sure each section is working:

```
=IF(MATCH(F2,Sheet2!A:A,0),"Position 1",IF(MATCH(G2,Sheet2!A:A,0),"position 2","other"))
```

Since the first statement worked to show position 1 then thinking adding second statement would give me position 2 but it isn't. Basically I get this:

```
column 1     column 2     column 3    Type Position
========     ========     ========    ==============
type 10      Type 3       Type 5      
Type 2       Type 12      Type 8      Pos 1
Type 4       Type 3       Type 6      
Type 1       Type 5       Type 11     Pos 1
```

I can't figure out why or is there a better way of doing this in excel?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: Types 1-3 would be unique per row?

Comment: @Pankaj Jaju Yes unique per row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions here:

1. Your columns 1, 2 & 3 are in columns F, G & H.
2. You are trying to match that data against whatever's in Sheet2, column A.

That being the case, try something like this, maybe:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(F2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"Position 1",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(G2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"position 2",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(H2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"position 3")))
```

Hope this does the trick...

Comment: Glad it worked - Since you're new to SO, remember to mark it as the accepted solution, then.